# remove () in keys created by FreqDist and ngrams

Tags: python, nltk

I used these codes to generate frequencies for ngrams

```
all_counts = FreqDist(ngrams(token, 1))
```

However, keys are in ().

```
FreqDist({('a',): 6,
          ('b',): 1,
          ('c',): 1})
```

I would like it to be as below:

```
FreqDist({'a': 6,
          'b': 1,
          'c': 1})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. It's unclear what the problem is. Are you concerned with the formatting of a printout?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I have edited the question. Hopefully it is clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Are the keys one-tuples: `('a',)`? Note the comma! Without that the parentheses don't actually do anything as you've shown them, so the question would be about string representation, not about the actual data structure. But if there is a comma, the parentheses are meaningful.

Comment: @Blckknght: you are right, there is ",". I just want the text, how to remove that "," also. Thanks.

Comment: based on nltk.FreqDist documentation, it looks like the return is a [tuple](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#ngrams)

Comment: You will don't have an MCVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_counts = {key[0] : val for key, val in all_counts.items()}
```

Comment: would you be able to modify the code for two words like this input: ```('a', 'b'): 6``` and output ```'a, b': 6```. Thanks.

Comment: please provide input and expected output, then I'll have a look